# Checking for word in message previous defined str disnake (discord.py)

Tags: python, discord.py

So I am making a command to post a message into a specific channel and I need to make it so payment option comes up if buying or selling is said instead of when advertising is selected. Anyway to do this? (Using disnake)

````
try:
          await asyncio.sleep(2)
          await channel2.send(f"Please send the Post type `Advertisement` , `Selling` , `Buying` {inter.author.mention}")
          msg = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120)
          PType = str(msg.content)
          await channel2.send("Please provide the name of the post:")
          msg2 = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120) 
          Pname = str(msg2.content)
          await channel2.send("Please provide the body of the post:")
          msg3 = await self.bot.wait_for('message', check=check, timeout=120) 
          Body = str(msg3.content)
          if "Advertisement" not in msg.content.lower():
            await channel2.send("Please Provide payment option")
            msg2 = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=120)
            Payment = str(msg2.content)
            await channel2.send("Please Provide payment amount")
            msg2 = await self.bot.wait_for("message", check=check, timeout=120)
            Amount = str(msg2.content)
          await channel2.send("Please wait for moderation to approve your message.")
          reportchannel = disnake.utils.get(guild.channels, id=920358352876355664)
          rem = disnake.Embed(title=f"New post created by {user.display_name}/{user.id}", description="-")
          rem.add_field(name=f"Post Type: {PType}", value=f"-")
          rem.add_field(name=f"{Pname}", value=f"{Body}")
          if "Advertisement" not in msg.content.lower():
            rem.add_field(name="Payment Type:", value=f"{Payment}")
            rem.add_field(name="Payment:", value=f"{Amount}")
          await reportchannel.send(embed=rem)
          await asyncio.sleep(15)
          await channel2.delete()
        except asyncio.TimeoutError:
          await channel2.delete()
          await user.send("Your channel was deleted due to a timeout. The time is limited to 120 seconds.")
    ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how to find if a word is in a string:

```
word = "example"
if word in example_string: 
   # do what you want here
```